# Excel - setting a cell equal to another cell with value results in 0 instead of the same value

Tags: excel

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

[image: Sample]

Thank you!!

Comment: Check if calculation mode is manual and set it to automatic?

Comment: [this](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/cell-reference-in-formula-always-returns-a-zero-value.2761446/) might be helpful. Other people had the same issue.

Comment: Calculation was set to automatic and cell didn't contain any trailing or leading spaces. In fact, none of the formulas were working. But I followed the link from @sophocles, found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Calculation was set to automatic and cell didn't contain any trailing or leading spaces. In fact, none of the formulas were working.

Simply click the Calculate Sheet option instead of Calculate Now option under the Formulas tab to fix this.

Found this solution in the link (https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/cell-reference-in-formula-always-returns-a-zero-value.2761446/) posted by @sophocles